# Restrict the search area when solving multiple nonlinear equations using SciPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, scipy, sympy, solver

I am trying to solve a large system of nonlinear equations using SciPy's general nonlinear solvers. All variables are restricted to a certain interval (for example consider percentage discounts, which must be in the range [0,1]).

Now my question: Is there a function (or a specific parameter setting), using which I can restrict the search area for variables to a certain interval.

Clearly, one option is to keep changing the initial value until I get a feasible solution. However, given the size of the problem, this is not efficient at all.

To clarify consider this example:

```
from scipy.optimize import *
from sympy import symbols
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify
x,y= symbols('x y')
y=lambdify(((x,y),),[x**2-x*y+y**2-21,x**2+2*x*y-8*y**2])
print(fsolve(y,[-1,-2]))
```

Is there any way one can get the positive solution of this system (which is, `[5.29, 2.65]`) in one shot without manipulating the initial guess?

Comment: You should at least apply the same constraints on your starting guess. Can you provide an example where you do so? There are algorithms for constrained optimization but not in SciPy last time I checked. You may also transform your equations with a sigmoidal function to "box in" your search space.